# Generate a semi-unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

I would like to generate a semi-unitary matrix, i.e., $UU^T=~I$ where U is a non-square matrix whose number of rows is bigger than its number of columns.
I tried it by solving the optimization problem $\min_U\|UU^T - I\|_F$ but didn't work at all since the problem is not convex.

Comment: Do you know how to generate a unitary matrix of a given size? If so, just generate one of size equal to the desired number of rows and remove the desired number of columns from the right side.

Comment: @Travis: I just tried that and didn't work. If that is correct then the identity matrix should satisfy what you just said but of course it does not..

Comment: I do believe you mean $U^T U = I$, which is an $n \times n$ matrix if $U$ is an $m \times n$ matrix; perhaps this resolves your issue?

Comment: What I meant is the identity matrix is a particular case of unitary matrix and if we pick up just the first columns we won't have $UU^T=~I$. I have also tried what you suggested with other unitary matrices and didn't work also.

Comment: the number of rows of $U$ can't be greater than the number of columns, as the rows are orthonormal!

Comment: @user251257: Do you mean such matrix doesn't exist?

Comment: @user2987 not with all conditions you want. either you have more rows then columns, then you probably meant $U^T U = I$. Or you have **more columns than rows** and $UU^T = I$.

Comment: @user251257 yeah I know but I am looking for that particular case or at least an approximate of the identity..

Comment: @user2987 you are looking for something that doesn't exist? I am confused. What do you need $U$ for? You could solve the minimal norm problem. But I don't understand what you are expecting to obtain. Its solution is surely not unique. The set of minimizer is not convex. There are probably non global minimizer.

Comment: @user251257 I understand that and I have mentioned it in my question that the problem is not convex.

Comment: @user2987 what property do you expect from a (local) minimizer of that approximation problem?

Comment: @user251257 I need at least $UU^T$ to be close enough to the Identity matrix (off-diagonal very small) or proportional to Identity.

Comment: @user2987 $UU^T$ will be a band matrix at best. The bandwidth is the numbers of rows $-$ columns. The squares of the off diagonal elements in each rows sum to $1$. So it is surely  nothing like the identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the simplest nontrivial case of this problem: you want 
$$
U = \begin{bmatrix}
a\\b
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with 
$$
UU^T = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
i.e.,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a^2  & ab \\ba & b^2
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Which requires that both $a$ and $b$ square to $1$, so each is $\pm 1$, but $ab = 0$; that's impossible.

A fancier explanation (for the general $n \times k$ problem) uses three helpful theorems:

- $rank(AB) \le max(rank(A), rank(B))$,
- the rank of an $n \times k$ matrix is no more than $min(n, k)$.
- $rank(A^T) = rank(A)$.

In your case, $k$ is the smaller number (more rows that cols), so the second and third tell you that $rank(U) = rank(U^T) \le k$; then the first tells you that $rank(UU^T) \le k$. But $rank(I_n) = n$, so you have a contradiction.

This latter argument is the one many mathematicians would make -- in its short form, it reads "the rank of the left side is no more than $k$, but the rank of the right is $n$, so it's impossible."

But the former argument is the result of a really useful approach to problems like this in linear algebra: **try the 2 or 3 simplest cases, and see whether you can come up with something.** If not, there's a decent chance there's no solution, or that the solutions for a low-dimensional subspace (or submanifold) of the domain; low-dimensional within a 2-, 3-, or 4-dimensional domain means "often not too hard to solve/check/examine by hand," and you can gain some real insight from this. I'd guess that half my answers to linear algebra questions on MSE follow this approach (often, like this one, hoping to instruct the questioner about how s/he might solve his/her own problems in the future).

You can also do numerical experiments: try 100,000 random $2 \times 1$ matrices and see whether any of them have $UU^t = I_2$. Pretty rapidly you'll notice a pattern. If there *were* a solution, even in a low-dim subspace, one of your test cases would likely have been near that subspace, so that the difference $UU^T - I$ would be small. If in all your examples, there's an entry of $UU^T - I$ that's at least, say, 1/2, then you're really unlikely to find a solution, and it's time to switch efforts from "I want to find a $U$ with this property" to "I want to prove that not such $U$ exists."

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have $UU^T = I$, you need is a matrix with more columns than rows, and whose rows are length-$1$ and mutually orthogonal.

Otherwise, the best you can do is find a matrix such that
$$
UU^T = \pmatrix{I_r & 0\\0&0}
$$
where $r$ is the rank of $U$ (i.e. the number of columns).

Comment: +1 oh right, if non unit rows are allowed, we get a better approximation to the identity. I forgot that :/

Comment: @user251257 I have no idea what you meant there

Comment: I thought that best approximation to the identity would be a band matrix, as I tried to keep the $1$ 's on the diagonal.

Comment: @user251257 oh, I see now.