# Clear difference between unitary matrix and semi-unitary matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

What are the clear differences between Unitary and Semi-unitary.

Comment: Unitary matrix: where $U^\dagger U=I$ or the Hermitian of $U$ (remember this is the conjugate transpose of $U$, and then $U^T$) times $U$ equals the identity matrix. (The Hermitian can also be written as $U^*$ or $\overline{U}^T$ as $\overline{U}$ stands for the conjugate transpose.)

Comment: Yes, I know. :) Is it possible to define it in math completely with difference semi-unitary?

Comment: I don't know what a semi-unitary matrix is, actually; I'm looking into it. =)

Comment: I have no idea if this definition is used anywhere else in the world, but here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403421/generate-a-semi-unitary-matrix

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A **unitary matrix** $U_{n\times n}$ is generally a complex matrix $U$ whose columns (or rows) constitute an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb C^n$. This means $$U^*U=UU^*=I$$
It is also invertible with $U^{−1} = U^∗$.

A **semi-unitary** matrix $U_{m\times n}$ is a non-square matrix ($m>n$ or $m<n$) where $U^*U=I_n$ or $UU^*=I_m$ which means either the rows or columns of the matrix are orthonormal.

Comment: Glad that it helped @Stephen

Answer (score -1):

**Unitary Matrix:** where $U^\dagger U=I$ (the Hermitian of $U$ times $U$ equaling the identity matrix)

**Semi-Unitary Matrix:** where $U^TU=I$ (the transpose of $U$ times $U$ equaling the identity matrix)

I'll be updating this with resources as I find them. Hope this helps!

Comment: @aminj, could you elaborate? I'd be glad to add stuff to my answer if that's what you need...